E0503: cannot use `self.index` because it was mutably borrowed
This code is a bit contrived but is a MRE.
struct Finder {
    data: Vec<String>,
    index: usize,
}

impl Finder {
    fn check_item(&self, needle: &str) -> Option<&str> {
        let item = &self.data[self.index];
        (item == needle).then_some(item.as_str())
    }

    //      ꜜ let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
    fn find(&mut self, needle: &str) -> Option<&str> {
        while self.index < self.data.len() {
            //                  ꜜ `*self` is borrowed here
            if let Some(item) = self.check_item(needle) {
                return Some(item); // returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
            }
            self.index += 1; // cannot use `self.index` because it was mutably borrowed
        }

        None
    }
}

Can someone explain what is wrong with this code? It looks like the use of check_item borrows &self for too long — it lasts all the way to the end of the loop body instead of just within the if let Some block. And I don't see how self.index is mutably borrowed at all. Is this a limitation of the borrow checker, or am I missing something?

Ok, so looks like I will have to find a workaround (such as moving the indexing operation out of check_item) until polonius lands?
